# What are some Spanish words that the Spaniards learned from the Pacific islanders, Philippines, etc

Tags: selección-de-palabras, palabras-raras, filipinas

We know the Spaniards borrowed a lot of words from Nahuatl. Having not much exposure to Spanish, words borrowed from the other parts of the Spanish Empire are unheard of for me. What words did the Spaniards pick up from the people of the Marianas, Philippines, Solomons, etc.?

Answer (score 6):

Searching the [**Dirae**](https://dirae.es) for "or. filipino" I have found a few words, like

> [Pantalán](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RiPycLB):
>   De **or. filipino**.
>   m. Muelle o embarcadero pequeño para barcos de poco tonelaje, que avanza algo en el mar.
>
> [Tao](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Z6LzD3g):
>   De **or. filipino**.
>   1. adj. En Filipinas, dicho de una persona: Plebeya, ordinaria o sencilla y analfabeta. U. t. c. s.

or

> [Chacón](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8SD1qQc):
>   De **or. filipino**.
>   1. m. p. us. Reptil de más de 30 cm de longitud, parecido a la salamanquesa, que se cría en Filipinas y se guarece por lo común en las grietas de los muros.

Others are [caracoa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7OKka4x), [sinamay](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XwXQ5h7), [nipis](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QWLB89s), etc.
Likewise, searching the DIRAE for "or. tagalo", "tagala", "malayo", "polinesio", etc, you can find many more words, some of them quite common, like **tabú**, **amok**, **orangután**, or **tatuar**.